# Serenity/js Cucumber Protractor : Tabs Capabilities & Features not visible in HTML reporting

Tags: serenity-js

I followed serenity-js guidelines but I don't see Capabilities and Feature tabs in HTML report. Only tests and acceptance criteria are visibles.

json output (maybe an issue with the path ???) :

```
{
    "id":"test-num-1;test-dosomething",
    "title":"Test something",
    "name":"Test something",
    "context":"chrome",
    "description":"",
    "startTime":1500459935525,
    "duration":5360,
    "testSource":"cucumber",
    "manual":false,
    "result":"SUCCESS",
    "userStory":{
        "id":"test-num-1",
        "path":"test\\e2e\\features\\capability_1\\myFeature1.feature",
        "storyName":"Test number 1",
        "type":"feature"
    },
    "tags":[
        {"name":"chrome","type":"browser"},
        {"name":"Test num 1","type":"feature"}
    ],
    "issues":[],
    "testSteps":[
        (...)
    ],
    "annotatedResult":"SUCCESS"
}
```

Is there any issue with path "test\e2e\" that prefix "features" path  ?

Thanks

Comment: The issue is with the path : moving file to ../../ give a json path  "path":"features\\capability_1\\myfeature1.feature"," and lost tabs are now visible in reporting.

Comment: Hi @S.L. I'm having the same issue here, how do you transform the path? Doing ..\\..\\e2e\\blabla or do you move the files themselves?

Comment: I finally moved protractor conf from /conf to / and moved all tests from e2e to /features like the typical structure you can find on serenity-js site for cucumber test. I think that serenity-js is not very customisable for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The process of producing the Serenity BDD HTML reports consists of two phases:

1. As your test scenarios are executed, [Serenity/JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serenity-js) generates `.json` and `.png` files under the [`outputDirectory`](http://serenity-js.org/overview/configuration.html#output-directory)
2. After your tests finish, [Serenity/JS CLI](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-cli-node) (a node.js wrapper around the [Serenity BDD CLI](https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-cli) jar) processes the above files, as well as the Cucumber feature files, to produce the HTML reports

This means that in order to make both Serenity/JS and Serenity/JS CLI use a non-default directory you'd need to:

- configure the [outputDirectory](http://serenity-js.org/overview/configuration.html#output-directory) of Serenity/JS
- specify the `source` (location of `.json` reports and screenshots) and `destination` (target location for the HTML report) parameters to be the same as the `outputDirectory` for Serenity/JS, and also the `features` property (location of Cucumber feature files) when [invoking Serenity/JS CLI](http://serenity-js.org/overview/configuration.html#output-directory)

Hope this helps!

Jan